# Exec.Command is executed, but has no effect on Windows 7

Tags: command-line, go, windows-7, system

I'm trying to print an local image from my Go program using [the Exec Package](http://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/) on Windows 7.

The following command line works fine when ran manually:

```
rundll32.exe shimgvw.dll ImageView_PrintTo /pt C:\Users\XXXXX\IMAGE.jpg "PRINTERNAME"
```

I tried:

```
res, err := exec.Command(
"cmd", 
"/c", 
"rundll32.exe", 
"shimgvw.dll", 
"ImageView_PrintTo", 
"/pt", 
"C:\\Users\\XXXXX\\IMAGE.jpg", 
"\"PRINTERNAME\"",
).Output();
```

or

```
res, err := exec.Command(
"cmd", 
"/c", 
"rundll32.exe shimgvw.dll ImageView_PrintTo /pt C:\\Users\\XXXXX\\IMAGE.jpg \"PRINTERNAME\"",
).Output();
```

But in both cases, it just sends back an empty string as a result and no error.
And no effect on the printer tasks list.

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious (something to do with the system environnement when executing the script?). Ideas are welcome!

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe it's just my windows inexperience but what is the extra `"cmd", "/c"`  for in the beginning?

Comment: I found several examples with those arguments (I guess it's allowing to load the dos environment in a proper command). I tried whithout them anyway, still the same issue.

Comment: BTW my script works on Unix, but this information seems irrelevant as the command line is different.

Comment: By the way, it's "Go" and "Go program", not "Golang script". Scripting and compiled languages are usually very different. Since you correctly used the "go" tag on the question there is no need to [force a tag into the title](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208/150469) as well (e.g. don't do "Go: the real title").

Comment: Ok thanks, I changed it.

Comment: I don't know go but assuming the exec takes one command and then the arguments then the first argument is /c and the second would probably be "rundll32.exe shimgvw.dll ImageView_PrintTo /pt C:\Users\XXXXX\IMAGE.jpg "PRINTERNAME"" please note the additional quotation marks. cmd /c takes the whole command to execute in quotation marks as parameter after /c. It might also be that quoatation marks are a special character and have to be escaped in the go language if you want to include them in the final call

Comment: Thanks for your help. I couldn't make it work. I tried so many versions... I'm certain the issue comes from the way to pass or encode the arguments.
As an alternative, I wrote a Node.js script to do the exact same task, it works fine.

Comment: Are you sure `PRINTERNAME` should be in its own quotes?

Comment: Yes, without them the commandline doesn't work even when executing manually.